# Solution to $(1-i)^n =2^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

---

Okay.
Find the integral solution of 
$$
(1-i)^n =2^n
$$

I just want to know who's to do this which is explained in as many steps as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible to give an explanation in as many steps as possible, sorry. Given an explanation, there exists another explanation with more steps.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Is that an _Incompleteness theorem for explanations_ ?

Comment: Okay. Just explain to me the basic idea as to how I can solve this question.

Comment: @Bernard Why, I suppose it is. I'm gonna be famous. Godel, Church, Turing, Ullrich... cool.

Comment: @Giridhar Hint: Write $1+i$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Okay could you do that please?

Comment: Hint. Try calculating the left-hand side for a few small values of $n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich could u do that for me?

Comment: Listen I'm really new to this and it would be of great help if u could solve this question for me

Comment: Okay. So I got it as $$ sqrt(2)* ((1/sqrt(2)) + (i/sqrt(2)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
|(1-i)^n| &= |2^n|\\
|1-i|^n &= |2|^n\\
(\sqrt2)^n &= 2^n
\end{align}$$

The only potential solution is $n=0$